# Changing html elements in a loop with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

so I have a slideshow banner.. which will also have 1.A quote (div containing it is `.msgSlide`) 2.A buttton (div containing it is `.btnSlide`) when each slide appears.. my current snippet for just the 1st slide is->

```
$(function() {
    $('.msgSlide').animate({left: "0%"}, 1000, function() {
        $('.msgSlide')
          .hide()
          .html("<p>Dream Big.. Never give up.</p>")
          .show()
          .animate({left: "40%"}, 1000)
          .animate({opacity: "0"}, 3000);
    });

    $('.btnSlide').animate({right: "0%"}, 2000, function() {
        $('.btnSlide')
          .hide()
          .html("<button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'>Learn more</button>")
          .show()
          .animate({right: "20%"}, 1000)
          .animate({opacity: "0"}, 2000);
    });
});
```

current snippet fiddle->http://jsfiddle.net/zzmm4fue/2/

I want to loop this pattern with different paragraphs & button texts depending on the no of slides!

Update-> i am trying something like this-> http://jsfiddle.net/zzmm4fue/3/ (not working though)

Comment: so?? what is your question? what is work? what is not? what a error? what do you mean with Changing html elements in a loop? where is your html code? or we should guess all of this?

Comment: it doesn't give an error.. the snippet i gave is for a single set of contents(quote+button).. what i want is a looped function that will run it for iterations! may be it will pull paragraph text & button value from an array!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/zzmm4fue/ update this with your code then update your question with the new jsfiddle .. it will be clear to anyone to understand what you trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok may be it was a basic problem that's why no one replied.. i have come up with the solution myself.. please suggest if u have a better solution

```
$(function() {
    var msgValue=["<p>Dream Big.. Never give up.</p>",
                    "<p>Some quote i haven't looked up yet.</p>",
                    "<p>I am not so good with quotes.</p>"],
        btnValue=["<button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'>Learn more</button>",
                    "<button class='btn btn-lg btn-warning'>Learn more</button>",
                    "<button class='btn btn-lg btn-danger'>Learn more</button>"],
        count=0;
    function loop(count) {
        $('.msgSlide')
                .css({left:0, opacity:0})
                .fadeIn(2000)
                .html(msgValue[count]);
        $('.msgSlide')
                .animate ({ left: '30%', opacity: '1'}, 1500, 'linear').fadeOut(2000);
        $('.btnSlide')
                .css({right:0, opacity:0})
                .fadeIn(2000)
                .html(btnValue[count]);
        $('.btnSlide')
                .animate ({ right: '30%', opacity: '1' }, 1500, 'linear').fadeOut(2000,
                function() {
                    loop(count);
                });
        count++;
        if(count==msgValue.length){ count=0; }
    }
    loop(count);
});
```

working fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/zzmm4fue/12/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for .. maybe it will need some arrangement .. but you can start from here

```
$(function() {
    var Divslength = $('.AnimateThis').length - 1;


    loopanimation($('.AnimateThis').eq(0));

    var count = 1;
    setInterval(function(){ 
        loopanimation($('.AnimateThis').eq(count));
        if(count == (Divslength)){
            count = 0;
        }else{
            count = count + 1;
        }
    },4000);
});

function loopanimation(el){
    $('.AnimateThis').fadeOut(300).css('z-index',0);
    el.css('z-index',1);
    el.fadeIn(300 , function(){
        el.find('.msgSlide')
              .animate({left: "-500px"}, 0)
              .hide()
              .html("<p>Dream Big.. Never give up.</p>")
              .show()
              .animate({left: "50%"}, 1000)
              .animate({left: "40%"}, 1000)
              .animate({opacity: "0"}, 3000)
              .animate({opacity: "1"}, 0)
        .animate({left: "-500px"}, 0);

         el.find('.btnSlide')
             .animate({right: "-500px"},0)
             .hide()
             .html("<button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'>Learn more</button>")
             .show()
             .animate({right: "30%"}, 1000)
             .animate({right: "20%"}, 1000)
             .animate({opacity: "0"}, 3000)
             .animate({opacity: "1"}, 0)
             .animate({right: "-500px"},0);
       });

}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/zzmm4fue/10/)

Comment: ur transition animation is gr8... but that's not the primary concern of mine.. i wanted to change the html contents of the divs! which is working in my solution which i gave

Comment: @NilanjanRoy http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/zzmm4fue/13/  .. if this is what you need just let me know to update my answer